# Can we mock the instance if it declared with new key word that is inside the method we are testing?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermockito

I'm new to Mockito and Junit, I'm working with Spring Boot

I want to know that can we mock the instance if it declared with a new keyword that is inside the method we are testing?

For example:

```java
@Service 
class A {

    @Autowired
    X x;

    @Autowired
    Y y;

    public void testMe(){
        imCommunicatingWithSomeRestClient();
    }

    private void imCommunicatingWithSomeRestClient(){
        String body="";
        MyRestClient client=new MyRestClient(iTakeUrlNeedsToHit); //no arg constructor not exist and suppose this is the method of some Core jar project
        client.callDataRest(HTTP.GET,body)
    }

}
```

Although I wanted to mock it, I've tried all `@Spy` `@Mock`, `@InjectMocks` to check if it'll behave differently but none of these worked for me as it always creates a new object and calls the real method.

So I change approach slightly and did it with using **BeanFactory** and instead of new I replace that with :

```java
MyRestClient client=beanFactory.getBean(MyRestClient.class,jobDataRestUrl);
```

so I have these questions:

1. Already asked above (if we mock the instance if it declared with new keyword that is inside the method we are testing).
2. If my current project is **Spring Boot** project and **MyRestClient** is inside the jar written in the core. Is the standard say I should not create it by Bean Factory because I think I should do it by that way and let the Spring handles that
3. I even tried with reflection but it seems it is also not working with the instance created with new keyword inside a method and not on the class level.

Answer (score 1):

Your current setting is not efficiently testable. You may still do it with lots of weird workarounds, but still, not recommended. Here's what you can do; firstly, you should not have any kind of dependency initialization inside your classes (like `new MyRestClient(...)`). So, move the REST client to the property level and have it injected through constructor.

```java
@Service
class A {
    private final X x;
    private final Y y;
    private final MyRestClient restClient;

    public A (X x, Y y, MyRestClient restClient) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.restClient = restClient;
    }

    public void testMe() {
        imCommunicatingWithSomeRestClient();
    }

    private void imCommunicatingWithSomeRestClient() {
        String body = "";
        restClient.callDataRest(GET, body);
    }
}
```

Since you are using Spring, you can create a bean of the REST client and move the endpoint URL to an external property.

```java
class Config {

    @Bean
    public MyRestClient myRestClient(@Value("${property.name}") String url) {
        return new MyRestClient(url);
    }

}
```

Finally, you can easily mock the behavior of that REST client.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestA {

    @Mock
    private X x;

    @Mock
    private Y y;

    @Mock
    private MyRestClient restClient;

    @InjectMocks
    private A a;

    // your tests...
}
```

Comment: so at the end aren't we creating the @Bean the bean through spring?

Comment: In application itself, yes, the bean is created by Spring, but in tests it is a mock